# Elliptic Curve Cryptography messages vs keys encryption

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have read a few tutorials about ECC implementaiton in C. What I am confused is this: Can I encrypt messages with ECC and without the use of any other algorithm, like AES, RSA or should I use them also?

What I mean is this: Can ECC alone can be used for text message encryption, or is it only for key generation?

Comment: Yes, you can but we prefer Hybrid encryption.

Comment: Why to prefer the Hybrid? You are talking about ECDSA? ECDH? What is the name of the none Hybrid ECC I can look at?

Comment: Speed? and just search and see [Hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridcryptosystem)

Comment: Can ECDSA or/and ECDH go faster than pure ECC? Yes, I will take a look...

Comment: No duplicate! I am asking about something very specific! Not ECC in general! Also I compare ECC to other known protocols...

Comment: @just_learning I don't see it. That question seems to be purely about ECC, you specify you want to do it *without* RSA / AES etc. Please indicate what particular part of your question is not answered by the Q/A indicated as duplicate. Please be as specific as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid cryptosystems, as @kelala has mentioned, are used in practice in favour of public-key encryption systems. It's not a particularity of Elliptic Curve vs Integer-Group based cryptosystems: it's rather that bit-twiddling (symmetric-key) cyphers are much faster than algebraic (public-key) ones.

So, what we do is to create a symmetric key and use a public-key scheme to encrypt it in the [KEM/DEM paradigm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/265.pdf) (and also [2](http://cryptowiki.net/index.php?title=KEM/DEM_technique_for_hybrid_encryption)) and then use a symmetric scheme to actually encrypt.

Also, keep in mind that even if you do encryption wholly in an Elliptic Curve, you probably need a hash function at some point that maps the text message (a sequence of bytes) to a field element or a curve point itself. 
You can look up the work of Icart, Fouque, Tibouchi, Coron, Maurer and others, for examples of how to do this (depending on the curve family you're targetting)